# QGIS 3.10 layout window: Where is the button to filter the legend by map content?

Tags: qgis

QGIS 3.10: I'm missing the filter-legend-by-map-content-button below the legend in the layout window. How to filter the legend without this button?

Comment: how did you loose the filter button? Did you tinker with the UI settings? Maybe a screenshot could provide usefull information

Comment: I did not change anything in the settings. In QGIS 3.4 and previous versions the button exists. But in 3.10 it is absent.